# Automapper, use to map object from Id returned from external API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have two classes, one db entity and one dto;

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DepartmentDto DepartmentDto { get; set; }
}
```

In this scenario, the Department isn't stored in the local database, it is called from an external api service;

```
// DepartmentApiWrapper.cs
public class DepartmentApiWrapper : IDepartmentApiWrapper
{
    public async Task<Department> GetDepartment(string id)
        // logic here to call from external api and return department

        return department;
    }
}
```

So what I want to do, when mapping an EmployeeDto from an Employee;

```
cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
```

When this map occurs, have it so that it uses the Id in the employee to call the DepartmentApiWrapper, to get the department, to then map that department to a DepartmentDto and assign it to the EmployeeDto.

The department info is from a shared repository, and can't be bought into the local database, it has to be called from an external api.

I'm not experienced in automapper and wouldn't know where to start on this, I can't even tell if it's something that can be done. I do know that we're using the static mapper - some clues suggest to use an instance mapper instead, although I couldn't figure out how to do implement this.

Any help would be appreciated, thank-you

Comment: You can pretty much do whatever you like in a [Custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters), although it could be rather difficult to debug the 'magic' of populating a `DepartmentDto` graph on the fly by enriching it from an external DB / API. At a suggestion, assuming departments are static and few in number, why not pre-load them all into a cache when you bootstrap your MVC app, keyed by `DepartmentId` - this way you can just do an in memory lookup. Just be careful not to mutate the shared Department!

Comment: Automapper is fundamentally used to map one object to another.  Once you introduce calling an API to retrieve data as part of your definition in a mapping then you're probably doing something wrong - you're breaking the single responsibility principal.

Comment: @StuartLC thats a very creative solution - thanks, I think I may well go with this. The data returned will be a list of employees, displaying their department. This could generate many db calls, would be a nightmare. -
- ODawg - you're right, as I'm just starting with automapper, seems like this would violate those principals. Probably best to avoid this. Thank-you.